# Скрипт php+mysql который удаляет запись если id больше 10

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Здравствуйте я хочу реализовать скрипт на php + mysql где запись автоматический будет удаляться если id записи будет больше 10
что то вроде
'DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` > 10'
этот код не работает или я ставлю ее куда то не туда

Comment: Что значит автоматически ? Спустя какое то время ? см. Cron задания (планировщик)

Comment: А зачем их тогда создавать?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас ошибка в запросе, у меня все сработало без ошибок.
Рабочий вариант:

```
$msqli->query('DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` > 10');
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не совсем понятно условие для автоматического удаления записи. И зачем их тогда создавать, если потом удалять? Улучшите свой вопрос для большей конкретики. А пока могу предложить 2 варианта:

- Первый - это использовать на стороне БД триггеры. При вставке проверять id записи и удалить нужную запись по условию. Если нужно удалить только что вставленную запись и у неё id>10, то её можно не вставлять вовсе. Отсюда вытекает второй вариант:
- Прежде чем вставлять запись, проверьте её id на стороне обработчика, и если он > 10, то либо не вставляйте её, либо удалите нужную. В данном случае это будет гораздо проще.